# What if we made this competition where we challenged people to make the coolest new rule?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, rules

**What if we made this competition where we challenged people to make the coolest, most useful, helpful, innovative, good new rule?**

So the winner would get like 200 rep, second, third place would get less and we would maybe implement this cool new rule on the respective site.

It would be like a meta post on each site. It would happen like every 2 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't really viable.

First, the community does get to - to some extent - drive the dialog for rule changes.

Second, these changes happen very quickly, and making one new change every 2 years would actually slow down the process.

Third, new ideas must be vetted, we can't just have random rules put in place because of a semblance of being "cool".

None of this is to say that new rules cannot be made. In fact, your post here uses the tool that is in essence how the community creates new rules.

If you would like something new to be implemented, then it **must** be researched. Once the research is complete, create a discussion talking about the conclusions from research into the topic. If the discussion yields a consensus then create a feature request, and devs willing it will get implemented.

Comment: So I would have researched how to community makes changes first